# introducir valor de la base de datos en un textarea

Tags: php, html

Mi error es:
Tengo un textarea, el cual relleno asi, le doy a enviar. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la base de datos se graba asi:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

 Y todo esta correcto. El problema viene cuando hago la llamada a ese campo dentro de un textarea. Que se muestra asi:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para mayor claridad. Aclarar que es un formulario para dar de alta productos, de modo que se rellena el formulario, y luego en la ficha del producto sale la información, en caso de mostrar ese mismo campo, en una tabla, se muestra sin problemas. Por lo que supongo que el problema esta en el textarea. ¿Alguien puede saber a que se debe eso? Robe a remplazar los caracteres con el php, pero no funciono. Y muchas mas funciones que encontré, pero ninguna me dio resultado.

Comment: Puedes mostrarnos cómo generas el campo textarea? Aplicas algún tipo de tratamiento al valor tras recuperarlo de la base de datos?

Comment: Simplemente era así 
"<textarea><?php echo $textarea[0][0]; ?></textarea>"
La variable estaba recién sacada de la base de datos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar `strip_tags()` para quitar las etiquetas `html`.

```
$texto_sin_etiquetas = strip_tags($contenido_textarea);
```

http://php.net/manual/es/function.strip-tags.php

También puedes utilizar en el textarea editores como CKEditor que interpretan las etiquetas html.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias. EL CKEditor es perfecto, no sabia que podían haber herramientas así totalmente gratuitas

Comment: No hay de que David, para eso estamos